# How to avoid typing \leavevmode before a citation macro that already starts with \leavevmode?

Tags: citing, optional-arguments, ntheorem, arguments, abntex2

[Control sequences with optional arguments inside optional arguments must
be "hidden" with braces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/205299).
Using the `abntex2cite` package to handle my citations, I often want to write:

```
\begin{teor}[{\cite[p.~42]{johndoe1999}}]
  $2+2=4$.
\end{teor}
```

That doesn't work, however; I need to write:

```
\begin{teor}[\leavevmode{\cite[p.~42]{johndoe1999}}]
  $2+2=4$.
\end{teor}
```

instead.
`\cite` and `\citeonline` behave exactly the same in this regard.
Besides `\leavevmode`, a `\strut` or just a space/end-of-line also work
(except the space looks weird/ugly).
That is, LaTeX needs something to start a line right before the citation macro between braces.
I thought that maybe this happens because the macros `\cite` and `\citeonline` had to start with `\leavevmode`, but don't;
however, [the source of `abntex2cite` shows that the very first line of `\citeonline` IS `\leavevmode`](https://github.com/abntex/abntex2/blob/f0a4d3c8589f0f2e7c087880f0816debda036eb4/tex/latex/abntex2/abntex2cite.sty#L679)!

So my questions are:

- Why is another `\leavevmode` before `\citeonline` (or `\cite`) necessary,
  even though `\citeonline` starts with `\leavevmode`?
- Is there a way to redefine `\cite` and `\citeonline` such that
  I don't need space/`\strut`/`\leavevmode` before the braced citation macro?

*(Files to showcase what I described)*

Contents of `sample.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{teor}{Teorema}
\newcommand*{\page}[1]{p.~#1}
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}


\begin{document}
Regular ``external'' citation according to the ABNT (Brazilian) standard:
\cite{johndoe1999}.

Regular ``inline'' citation according to the ABNT (Brazilian) standard:
\citeonline{johndoe1999}.

So far, so good; no extra braces needed.
Whithin the optional argument of an environment, however,
extra braces are needed:

\begin{teor}[This works
  {\cite[\page{25}]{johndoe1999}}%<-- notice the extra braces!
  ]
  Notice the extra braces in the optional argument.
\end{teor}

\begin{teor}[Also works
  {\citeonline[\page{25}]{johndoe1999}}%<-- notice the extra braces!
  ]
  Notice the extra braces in the optional argument.
\end{teor}

And the next one works, but it requires
(besides the extra braces)
something to start a line before \verb|\cite| or \verb|\citeonline|:
it can be a space, a \verb|\strut| or \verb|\leavevmode|.
I think that's annoying and error-prone;
is there another way?

\begin{teor}[% avoid extraneous space here
  \leavevmode{\citeonline[\page{25}]{johndoe1999}}%<-- \leavevmode + extra braces!
  ]
  This one requires both
  extra braces AND ``something to start a line''
  in the optional argument.
\end{teor}

\bibliography{bibfile}
% this is how a chapter of a book is supposed to look in the ABNT style...
\end{document}

% -- the following won't compile!
% erase the previous 2 macros to generate errors
\begin{teor}[% lacks \leavevmode AND extra braces
  \citeonline[\page{25}]{johndoe1999}%
  ]
  \fbox{content}
\end{teor}

\begin{teor}[% lacks extra braces: {\citeonline...}
  \leavevmode\citeonline[\page{25}]{johndoe1999}%
  ]
  \fbox{content}
\end{teor}

\begin{teor}[% lacks \leavevmode (or \strut)
  {\citeonline[\page{25}]{johndoe1999}}%
  ]
  \fbox{content}
\end{teor}

\bibliography{bibfile}
\end{document}
```

Contents of `bibfile.bib`:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8
@InCollection{johndoe1999,
  author    = {Doe, John},
  booktitle = {Handbook of Foobar},
  publisher = {Barbaz},
  title     = {Interesting chapter},
  year      = {1999},
  address   = {Earth},
  editor    = {{Mc}Editor, Editor},
  pages     = {283--342},
}
```

[image: problem showcase]

Comment: I'm not familiar with the document class you're using, but I would look at the definition of `\newtheorem` and friends to see if something there might be responsible for disabling `\leavevmode` if the first thing within the optional argument is an open brace.  (After all, when the optional argument starts with text, it works.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is obviously due to `ntheorem`: if I remove it, the issue disappears.

If you really need it (personally, I wouldn't use it), I can propose a workaround:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@InCollection{johndoe1999,
  author    = {Doe, John},
  booktitle = {Handbook of Foobar},
  publisher = {Barbaz},
  title     = {Interesting chapter},
  year      = {1999},
  address   = {Earth},
  editor    = {{Mc}Editor, Editor},
  pages     = {283--342},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}
\usepackage{ntheorem}

\newtheorem{teor}{Teorema}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\fixtheorem}{m}
 {
  \cs_set_eq:cc { #1@fixed } { #1 }
  \cs_set_eq:cc { end#1@fixed } { end#1 }
  \RenewDocumentEnvironment{#1}{o}
   {
    \IfNoValueTF{##1}{\use:c{#1@fixed}}{\use:c{#1@fixed}[\exp_not:n{##1}]}
   }
   {
    \use:c{end#1@fixed}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\fixtheorem{teor}

\newcommand*{\page}[1]{p.~#1}

\begin{document}

Regular ``external'' citation according to the ABNT (Brazilian) standard:
\cite{johndoe1999}.

Regular ``inline'' citation according to the ABNT (Brazilian) standard:
\citeonline{johndoe1999}.

So far, so good; no extra braces needed.
Whithin the optional argument of an environment, however,
extra braces are needed:

\begin{teor}[This works {\cite[\page{25}]{johndoe1999}}]
Notice the extra braces in the optional argument.
\end{teor}

\begin{teor}[Also works {\citeonline[\page{25}]{johndoe1999}}]
Notice the extra braces in the optional argument.
\end{teor}

And the next one works, but it requires
(besides the extra braces)
something to start a line before \verb|\cite| or \verb|\citeonline|:
it can be a space, a \verb|\strut| or \verb|\leavevmode|.
I think that's annoying and error-prone;
is there another way?

\begin{teor}[{\cite[\page{25}]{johndoe1999}}]
This one requires both extra braces AND ``something to start a line'' 
in the optional argument.
\end{teor}

\begin{teor}[{\citeonline[\page{25}]{johndoe1999}}]
This one requires both extra braces AND ``something to start a line'' 
in the optional argument.
\end{teor}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

The original `teor` is renamed `teor@fixed` and a more robust `teor` environment is defined, with the optional argument protected from the untimely expansion done by `ntheorem`.

This also has a little advantage, in that you can even omit the inner braces and

```
\begin{teor}[\cite[\page{25}]{johndoe1999}]
```

would work.

[image]